# Correct Cursor indentation on the new line after the semicolon in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ide, visual-studio-code, text-editor

I wish the cursor to be indented properly when I press enter after the semicolon. How can I achieve this in VS Code?

[image: CT]

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off `wrappingIndent`, or set it back to default `same`, and then ensure `formatOnType` is set to true:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.wrappingIndent": "same",
    "editor.formatOnType": true
},
```

This will put all the new lines the same as the previous, as you type it will automatically indent, where applicable:

```
cy.visit('/admin/settings/categories/add')
  .get('[data-cy=name]').type('category')
```

[image]

As shown you would have to explicitly press 'Enter'; it doesn't work if you use shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

One thing none of these wrapper-like settings will take into account is context; say you want to deep indent after the first .get(), arbitrarily for illustration:

```
cy.visit('/admin/settings/categories/add')
    .get('[data-cy=name]').type('category')
        .checkDb('Category', { name: 'Category 2' })
    .get('[data-cy=submit]').click();
```

The native formatter will automatically put it back in line with the other children.

This would ultimately need native [extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/javascript)/`onEnter` support

Comment: I applied the same settings but it does not seem to be working for me. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm not sure @Gaurav it's possible you have an extension or something conflicting. I don't use any formaters like Prettier. I'm a minimalist with extensions. You can try running from the command line and disabling extensions to verify : `code --disable-extensions`. It's possible it could be another setting I have that is contributing, I'll double check

Comment: I've double-checked, it is the only settings I've used with the `--disable-extensions` flag and using a clean user-data-dir

Comment: Worked like a charm for me but I configured the global editor settings, not only for JS.